# Going to child route does not persist VueX state

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

So I have child route:

```
 {path: '/news/:id',
   component: () => import('../views/NewsDetail.vue'), 
   props: true
  },
```

Now I when I go to this route from different view/component in my app:

```
 <v-list-item-title class="pb-2"><a :href="'/news/'+this.id">{{title}}</a></v-list-item-title>
```

However going to this route VueX state refreshes back to base state. Why is that so?

Comment: can you use <router-link> or `$router.push` ? i guess you reload your window and js memory with a :href

Answer (score 0):

You need use [router-link](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link) instead:

```
<v-list-item-title class="pb-2">
  <router-link :to="`/news/${id}`">
    {{ title }}
  </router-link>
</v-list-item-title>
```